# How to predict from new data set?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, speech-recognition

I have created a model to predict emotion from a voice sample, the model is made from the code below:

there are total 8 emotions:
neutral, calm, happy, sad, angry, disgust, surprised

i first extracted the features of each and every voice sample and put them in a dataframe, then loaded
them one by one to both X and (labels to Y) then split the data as shown below:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=0, shuffle=True)

scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)

x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=2)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=2)

model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(Conv1D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(units=8, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.summary()

rlrp = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.4, verbose=0, patience=2, min_lr=0.0000001)
history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=75, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[rlrp])
```

got total 89% accuracy

Now i want to predict with a new dataset. What do i need to do?

Comment: Your question is not clear. I assume you are asking how can I use the model? If so you should save the model for future predictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `new_data_x_test` and `new_data_y_true` are your new data set, then all you need to do after training the model as follows:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
new_data_x_test = scaler.transform(new_data_x_test )
new_data_x_test= np.expand_dims(new_data_x_test, axis=2)

model.load_weight(h5)
new_data_y_pred = model.predict(new_data_x_test )
```

The thing is, you should transform it according to the model requirements. Next, evaluate on `new_data_y_true` and `new_data_y_pred`  with appropriate evaluation metrics.